# Showing validation errors in a modal pop up in mvc view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I have a main view in which I am calling a partial view 'Add'. This Add view is a form with a submit button and I am displaying it as a modal pop up box.
To submit the form, I am making an ajax call to an action method. Now, I need two things-
1. If data posted is valid, then display a success message and close the modal
2. If there is any validation error, show them on the modal pop up while highlighting the fields.
 I am using twitter bootstrap for displaying the modal.
Ajax call :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: urlForSavingAdd,
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'application/JSON',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status) {
                $('#divAddNew').html(data.Message);
                $('#divAddNew').fadeOut();
                },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               var errorMessage = xhr.responseText;
               $('#divAddNew').html(errorMessage);
              $('#divAddNew').show();
        }
    });
```

Controller -

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Add(SomeModel add)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save item to DB
                return Json(new
                {
                   Message = "Record saved successfully to the Database."
                });
         }
        else
        {
                return Json(new
                    {
                   Message = GetModelStateErrors(this.ModelState);
                     });
         }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?  What isn't working?

Comment: I got it working by sending appropriate Json messages from action method back to the ajax call and then I parse through the response to display messages accordingly.